# How to fetch ip and mac addresses of all the devices connected to another LAN using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, ip, mac-address

How to fetch ip and mac addresses of all the devices connected to different LAN in the same organization using nodejs or any powershell script ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find by using `child_process`

Something like this.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function os_func() {
    this.execCommand = function(cmd, callback) {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            callback(stdout);
        });
    }
}

var os = new os_func();
os.execCommand('arp -a', function (returnvalue) {
    console.log(returnvalue)
});
```

or you can use `arp-scan`
install
`sudo apt-get install arp-scan`

The just change the command `sudo arp-scan -l`

This will get you all info

Comment: Hi Mayank, thank you for answering but after executing this code, i am able to fetch the ip's which are connected to my LAN, is it possible to fetch the ip addresses connected to another LAN (devices having different default gateway) ?

Comment: How can we install arp-scan package in windows?  As in Debian GNU/Linux OS we can install arp-scan using sudo apt-get install arp-scan, then how can we install it in windows?.......I tried installing "npm i arpscan new" package and executed this code but got  the error  "exec is not a function"

Comment: you can check in windows. There will be alternative for `arp-scan` you will have to just change `cmd`. Code will return you everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this PowerShell script with any windows machine. Put your hostname in to hostname text. As long as you can able to ping the hostname where you are running the script.

---

```
$hostname = get-content -path "C:\temp\hostname.txt"

Foreach ($computer in $hostname) {

   $ping =  Test-Connection -Name $computer -count 2 -Quiet 

   If ($ping -eq $true) {

    $prop = Get-Ciminstance -ClassName Win32_NetorkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | select IPAddress, MacAddress, PSComputerName
    Write-Host $prop

   }

}
```

Comment: Hi, you can definitely write the solution to your own answer, bug can you post it as a question and then put your solution in it as well. Here's also a post on how to format your code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks